# Segmentation fault while loading yolov5 model

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, yolov5

I'm loading a yolov5 model. However, while running it is raising a `Segmentation fault` exception.

Here's my code.

```
import torch
humanModel = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s')
humanModel.classes = [0]
```

Following is the terminal output, upon running the above script.

```
Using cache found in /Users/prafulbagai/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master
YOLOv5  2022-11-18 Python-3.9.13 torch-1.13.0 CPU

Fusing layers...
YOLOv5s summary: 213 layers, 7225885 parameters, 0 gradients
Adding AutoShape...
zsh: segmentation fault  python3 humans.py
```

I'm quite a newbie in ML models, hence unable to understand the exact reason behind it. It sometimes work, the other times it raises the above error. How can it be fixed?